# Stored procedure to handle null parameter

Tags: sql-server, null

I'm sure this has a very simple answer I am not finding...  I have a simple hierarchy in a database where each row has a ParentId.  If `ParentId IS NULL`, then it's a root element.  I have the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetByParent @parentId int
AS BEGIN SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE ParentId = @parentId END
```

It works fine if I send an integer, but if I send `NULL` it becomes `ParentId = NULL`, which doesn't work in ANSI.  I know there is `COALESCE(@parentId, ParentId)`, but that returns all rows when `@parentId IS NULL`.  I can do an IF ELSE statement and copy the query (one with `= @parentId` and the other with `IS NULL`), but I'm sure there's a better way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Handle the NULL case in a separate condition:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE1
WHERE ParentId = @parentId
    OR (ParentId IS NULL AND @parentId IS NULL)
```

Comment: That's it... it didn't cross my mind to use `COALESCE` on both sides.

Comment: I took the COALESCE version out and replaced it with this current version.  On a large table, COALESCE(ParentId) could cause performance issues by triggering a table scan.  With this current version, the query planner should still use any index that you have on ParentId.

Answer (score 4):

I'm making the assumption that you are not using negative ids for parentID.

If you use two ISNULL statements, you can cover all the cases in one query:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE ISNULL(ParentId,-1) = ISNULL(@parentId,-1)
```

This way when @parentid IS NULL, it will  only return results with null values, instead of all rows.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the IF/ELSE method is the most performant short of using dynamic SQL.  Assuming SQL Server 2005+, you'd use:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(max)
   SET @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE 1=1 '

   SET @SQL = CASE 
                WHEN @parentid IS NULL THEN ' AND parentid IS NULL '
                ELSE ' AND parentid = @parentid '
              END

BEGIN

  EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'parentid INT', @parentid

END
```

Obligatory IF/ELSE:

```
BEGIN

  IF @parentid IS NULL
  BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE parentid IS NULL 
  END
  ELSE
  BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE parentid = @parentid
  END

END
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought of using dynamic SQL, but it seemed like overkill.  I had it with the if/else, but I don't like having to repeat everything (columns to select, joins, etc.).  I'm not too worried about performance here since it's a fairly small/flat hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

you could just use an OR statement

... 
`WHERE (@parentId IS NULL AND ParentId IS NULL) OR ParentId=@parentId`