# change conditions when parameter is null

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Table_Search

@param1 VARCHAR(100) = NULL,
@param2 VARCHAR(100) = NULL,
@param3 VARCHAR(100) = NULL
AS

SELECT * FROM Table1
WHERE
column1 LIKE '%' + @param1 + '%'
AND
column2 
IN 
(
    SELECT * FROM Table2
    WHERE
    CONTAINS(column3,@param2)
    AND
    column4 
    IN
    (
        SELECT * FROM 
        fn_SplitWords(@param3,',')
    )
)
```

what i want to happen is when  `@param1 IS NOT NULL @param2 IS NULL AND @param3 IS NULL`, the stored procedure will be like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Table_Search
@param1 VARCHAR(100) = NULL,
@param2 VARCHAR(100) = NULL,
@param3 VARCHAR(100) = NULL
AS

SELECT * FROM Table1
WHERE
column1 LIKE '%' + @param1 + '%'
```

and when `@param2 IS NOT NULL AND @param3 IS NULL`, the stored procedure will be like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Table_Search

@param1 VARCHAR(100) = NULL,
@param2 VARCHAR(100) = NULL,
@param3 VARCHAR(100) = NULL
AS

SELECT * FROM Table1
WHERE
column1 LIKE '%' + @param1 + '%'
AND
column2 
IN 
(
    SELECT * FROM Table2
    WHERE
    CONTAINS(column3,@param2)
)
```

I already visited 
[WHERE IS NULL, IS NOT NULL or NO WHERE clause depending on SQL Server parameter value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/810714/where-is-null-is-not-null-or-no-where-clause-depending-on-sql-server-parameter)
and [Stored procedure to handle null parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3097554/stored-procedure-to-handle-null-parameter)
but I believe that this is a different case.

What might be the possible approach for this?

Comment: Erland Sommarskog's [Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html)

Comment: You can convert your comment to an answer to close this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
WHERE
column1 LIKE '%' + ISNULL(@param1, column1) + '%' AND
column2 LIKE '%' + ISNULL(@param2, column2) + '%' AND
...
```

This filters on every field if the parameter is set.

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically build your sql statement and then executesql proc to execute your query something like this...

```
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @Sql = N'SELECT * FROM Table1
            WHERE 1 = 1 '

IF (@param1 IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
  SET @Sql = @Sql + N' AND column1 LIKE ''%@param1%'''
END

IF (@param2 IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
SET @Sql = @Sql + N' AND column2  IN (
                                        SELECT * FROM Table2
                                        WHERE
                                        CONTAINS(column3,@param2)
                                     )'
END

IF (@param3 IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
 SET @Sql = @Sql + N' AND column4 
                                IN
                                (
                                    SELECT * FROM 
                                    fn_SplitWords(@param3,'','')
                                )
                            '
END


EXECUTE sp_executesql @Sql
                    , N'@param1 VARCHAR(100),@param2 VARCHAR(100),@param3 VARCHAR(100)'
                    , @param1, @param2, @param3
```